# Как запустить сервер "Jupyter Notebook" и получить доступ из Python-блокнотов в VSCode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Вопрос такого характера:

- В Редакторе `VSCode` устанавливаем необходимые зависимости `Python + Jupyter`.
- Создаем `.venv`.
- Создаем блокнот `*.ipynb` и пытаемся выполнить любой код. VSCode предлагает выбрать `.venv` и установить необходимые зависимости.
- После чего код успешно выполняется.

Но!!! Нужно запустить Python-скрипт из стороннего процесса к среде которого нет доступа и запустить в нем сервер "Jupyter Notebook". Все что я могу это добавить пути:

```py
sys.path.append(project_path)
site.addsitedir(os.path.join(project_path, ".venv", "Lib", "site-packages"))

# Здесь(в site-packages) есть такие пакеты
import jupyter_core
import jupyter_client

# и скрипт
import jupyter
```

... Как теперь запустить, то(не знаю что) что запускает VSCode, что'б можно было подключиться через `*.ipynb` и выполнять код в стороннем процессе?